# Lucene Index- Sitecore Web index _sat0.cfs file is missing

Tags: indexing, lucene, index

We are using Lucene index in Sitecore environment. We are facing file not found issue recently in the web page. master index is working fine but in master index there is no file related to this name.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\Data\indexes\sitecore_web_index\_sat0.cfs'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\Data\indexes\sitecore_web_index\_sat0.cfs'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\Data\indexes\sitecore_web_index\_sat0.cfs'.]
   Lucene.Net.Index.FindSegmentsFile.Run(IndexCommit commit) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Index\SegmentInfos.cs:736
   Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.Open(Directory directory, IndexDeletionPolicy deletionPolicy, IndexCommit commit, Boolean readOnly, Int32 termInfosIndexDivisor) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Index\DirectoryReader.cs:117
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Sharding.LuceneShard.<CreateReader>b__11_0(LuceneIndexAccess access) +73
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Sharding.LuceneShard.CreateReader(LuceneIndexAccess indexAccess) +161
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Sharding.LuceneShard.CreateSearcher(LuceneIndexAccess indexAccess) +52
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +78
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +158
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +93
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchContext.Initialize(ILuceneProviderIndex index, ILuceneProviderSearchable[] searchables, LuceneIndexAccess indexAccess) +173
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex.CreateSearchContext(SearchSecurityOptions securityOptions) +110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could try and eliminate first..

- **File locking:** Do you have a virus checker that could be locking the files and stopping them from being overwritten or possibly deleting them? Do you have drive sharing that could cause issues like this.
- **Permissions:** Do the Data and indexes folders have the correct permissions i.e. does the user the IIS worker process is running under (e.g. NETWORK SERVICE) have write and delete access to these folders.
- **Configuration:** Check that nothing has changed any of the Lucene index definitions in the Sitecore section of the web.config.

Rebuilding the index via the control panel or go into the Data\indexes\sitecore_web_index directory and delete everything in there before you do the rebuild just in case anything has corrupted something in the existing index. Depending on how many items you have the index shouldn't take very long at all, so if it hangs like that it normally indicates a problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @sumit. I have deleted the all the indexes from the folder. Then rebuild the index after that it is working fine.